# If a prime (of the form $4k+3$) divides the sum of two squares, then it divides each of the two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

> **Statement :** A prime $p$ is of the form : $3 \pmod 4$. Show that if $p \mid a^2+b^2$, then $p \mid a$ and $p\mid b$.

I don't know exactly how to proceed. I got the following proof from somewhere:

> Assuming that $p\mid a^2+b^2$ and $p\nmid a$, we get that $\exists k \ni ak\equiv 1 \pmod p \implies (ak)^2+(bk)^2\equiv k^2(a^2+b^2)\equiv 0 \pmod p \implies (bk)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$. And this is a contradiction.

Please explain me why $(bk)^2\equiv -1 \pmod p$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: It doesn't. $(bk)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ leads to a contradiction. There's a difference between $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm sorry. It was a typographical error.

Answer (score 4):

It's not $(bk)^2\equiv1\pmod p$ that gives a contradiction, it's
$(bk)^2\equiv-1\pmod p$.

This is in every textbook on number theory, but here goes. Let $p=4k+3$
be prime and suppose $c^2\equiv-1\pmod p$. Then $c^{4k+2}\equiv(-1)^{2k+1}\equiv-1\pmod p$ but this states that $c^{p-1}\equiv-1\pmod p$ which contradicts Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. Using Euler's criterion and Legendre's symbol,

$$\binom{-1}{p} = (-1) ^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1$$

This means that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$, so $\nexists (bk) \in \mathbb{Z} : (bk)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$